# Error attempting to login to Arrow Cloud

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Actually I am not capable to login to Appcelerator Studio. It's throw this message when I try to login via appc login.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be because of the **outdated cli** version. Just go into **"Check for updates"** in menu of appecelarator and if it is showing new CLI available then pls download it.

Hope this will solve the issue :)

Comment: Yeah...They are no longer allowing to use that version. I solved by my own few days ago, but the reason was this one